# Backbone.Models#save callbacks are not being triggered

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, express, coffeescript

I have a small `Backbone`/`Express` app with a model called `JobStatuses` that I'd like to occasionally sync. The Backbone documentation states that:

> save accepts success and error callbacks in the options hash, which
>   will be passed the arguments (model, response, options). If a
>   server-side validation fails, return a non-200 HTTP response code,
>   along with an error response in text or JSON.

However, when I call `JobStatuses.save`, I see from my console that despite the fact that the server returned status 200, my `success`/`failure` call backs are not getting triggered. Here's the code for my my view, model, and the route with the server-side handler function. `updateJobs` is the function that gets called. Why aren't my `JobStatuses.save` callbacks getting triggered?

This is the view that calls `JobStatuses.save`. I can confirm that the `render` function does get called here.

```
reqs = ['jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore', '../models/jobstatuses']
define(reqs, ($, Backbone, _, JobStatuses)->
  class ButtonView extends Backbone.View
    el: $('.button-container'),
    template: _.template($('#button-template').html())
    constructor: ()->
      this.listenTo(JobStatuses, 'sync', this.render)
      this.listenTo(JobStatuses, 'save', this.render)
      JobStatuses.fetch()
    render: ()->
      this.el.html(this.template(jobStatuses: JobStatuses.attributes))
      this.buttons = this.el.find('.job-button')
      this.buttons.click(()->
        category = $(this).attr('category')
        job = $(this).attr('job')
        JobStatuses.attributes[category][job] = 'Completed'
        JobStatuses.save(
          success: (() ->
            console.log('statuses')
            console.log(JobStatuses.attributes)),
          error: (()->
            console.log('failure'))
        )
      )
)
```

The `JobStatuses` model:

```
define(['backbone'], (Backbone)->
  class JobStatuses extends Backbone.Model
    url: '/jobs'

  new JobStatuses
)
```

My route. `updateJobs` is the only one that gets called here:

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */
var RUNNING = 'Running';
var COMPLETED = 'Completed';
var BLOCKED = 'Blocked';
var NOT_STARTED = 'Not started';

var jobs = {
  'oon': {
    'oonload': NOT_STARTED,
    'oonstagecopy': NOT_STARTED
  },
  'icd': {
    'icdload': NOT_STARTED,
    'icdstagecopy': NOT_STARTED
  }
}

exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Backbonejs Batchstart' });
};

exports.getJobs = function(req, res){
  //res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(jobs));
};

exports.updateJobs = function(req, res){
  jobs = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(jobs);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(jobs));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the extra parenthesis around your success and error functions, ie:

```
success: (() ->
        console.log('statuses')
        console.log(JobStatuses.attributes)),
```

to

```
success: () ->
        console.log('statuses')
        console.log(JobStatuses.attributes)
```

It also looks like the problem is your save call as you must specify what is to be saved.  If you just want to update the model based on it's current changed state, then call save with an empty object literal like so:

```
JobStatuses.save({},
```

Alternatively you could just add the line with the attribute change to the save call like so:

```
JobStatuses.save(
  category: job: 'completed'
,
  success: () ->
```

Comment: you also have to specify what to save, try throwing an empty object literal as the first param of the save call ie JobStatuses.save( to JobStatuses.save({},

Comment: Ah, I knew I missed something. Thanks, that worked. If you make that the answer I can accept it.